# Unable to call payable function from node console

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, payable

I am trying to execute following function

```
    function createSurvey() external payable notTheOwner returns(uint surveyId, address newSurveyAddress) {
    require(msg.value > surveyCreationFees);

    uint surveyReward = msg.value.sub(surveyCreationFees);

    address _newSurveyAddress = (new Survey).value(surveyReward)(msg.sender);
    uint _surveyId = surveys.push(_newSurveyAddress).sub(1);
    surveyToOwner[_surveyId] = msg.sender;


    SurveyCreated(_surveyId, _newSurveyAddress);
    return (_surveyId, _newSurveyAddress);
}
```

Contract is deployed using account 0 and I am trying to call a function from account 1

I have tried following :

```
> surveyfactory.createSurvey.call({value: 100, from: web3.eth.accounts[1], to: web3.eth.accounts[0]})
```

> Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
>       at Object.InvalidResponse (/home/zcon/ethereum_voting_dapp/chapter1/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:16)
>       at RequestManager.send (/home/zcon/ethereum_voting_dapp/chapter1/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:61:22)
>       at Eth.send [as call] (/home/zcon/ethereum_voting_dapp/chapter1/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:145:58)
>       at SolidityFunction.call (/home/zcon/ethereum_voting_dapp/chapter1/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/function.js:135:32)

I have also tried

```
surveyfactory.createSurvey.call({value:4000,from:web3.eth.accounts[1]})
```

Complete code of contract is available [here](https://blog.amr-gawish.com/building-a-production-ready-ethereum-dapp-from-idea-to-final-product-the-smart-contract-pt-3-2e117c74e61e)

```
value I am sending is greater than surveyCreationFees
```

Comment: I think you want `sendTransaction`, not `call`.

Comment: No I have tried sendTransaction, it is also not working

Comment: > surveyfactory.createSurvey.sendTransaction({value : web3.toWei('100000', 'wei') , from : web3.eth.accounts[1]})
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
    at Object.InvalidResponse

Comment: Either debug the transaction to see where it's failing or just remove things until it succeeds. (The function is small; it should only take a minute or two to figure out which line is causing the `revert`. From there it should be easy to debug.)